# How to format cell as currency using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have started learning Apache POI and want to format a cell like this

```
$ 1,200.00
$ 12,500.00
```

How to do this?
Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for formatting number here:-
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html